# problems with lapply and function

Tags: r, function, lapply

I've been attempting to use lapply with a function that is applied to a list of data frames. However, I obtain warning messages stating that the Name is partially matched in the data frame. i.e. I am unable to get the function to apply to the list of data frames. I have tested the code for one individual data frame, which works correctly. Can somebody offer me some advice on this matter.

For example,

```
dflist = list("species1", "species2", "species3", "species4", "species5")
myFunc <- function(DF = dflist) {
  DF <- merge(df_main, DF, all.x=TRUE)
  DF$count[is.na(DF$count)] <- 0
  return(DF)
}
lapply(X = dflist, FUN=myFunc)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your code works fine for the example I created `set.seed(24);df_main <- data.frame(Col1= LETTERS[1:20], count1=sample(1:20,20, replace=TRUE));set.seed(342); lst <- lapply(1:5, function(i) data.frame(Col1=sample(LETTERS[1:20], 10, replace=FALSE), count=sample(1:20,10, replace=TRUE)) ); lapply(lst, myFunc)`

Comment: It will be better if you post some example that gives the warning

Comment: ... and do post the exact warning.